# React Create simple form

Tags: reactjs

I've just started to learn React and I would like to create simple page with form. Form should contain inputs `keywords` and `city`, select list `date` and submit buttom.

It's structure of my project
[image]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <div class="form-container"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import './bootstrap.min.css';
import './SearchForm.js';
```

**SearchForm.js**

```
const formContainer = document.querySelector('.form-container')

class SeacrhForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
       keywords: '',
       city: '',
       date: ''     
      }

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
     }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <form className='search-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h1>Say Hi!</h1>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SeacrhForm />, formContainer)
```

And I got errors on my page in browser
[image]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay You need to add the following imports to you searchform.js file

```
import React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

and remove this line:

```
const formContainer = document.querySelector('.form-container')
```

And don't change the index.html file ever, instead create a new component like you have created searchform.js and render it in app.js and then react will automatically render that component inside

```
<div id=root></div>
```

you may not need to manually do it.
check out the following link, It may help you to understand reactJs better.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html

Comment: But how to connect `index.html` and `App.js` ? What  should `App.js` contain in this case?

Comment: @Heidel you need a bundler like `webpack`

Comment: Okay since you are a beginner , I am not going into deep knowlege , You just need to run this command in you terminal "create-react-app <appname>" it will initialize a new project with app.js linked to index.html. Although I suggest you to go through the docs thoroughly to get a clear view of what is happening.

Comment: But how to render `SearchForm.js` in `App.js` ? I added `import './SearchForm.js';` at the top `App.js`, but what's next?

Comment: import statement should be changed to "import SearchForm from '<path to file>'" and you need to provide the code of app.js

Answer (score 1):

Add

- `import React from 'react'`
- `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'`

to `SearchForm.js`

Modern JS works well with ES modules, that means that you need to import dependencies into every file(module), otherwise such libraries will not be available.